# A method that accepts both mutable and immutable map in Scala

Tags: scala

How can I change the signature of this method to a method that accepts both mutable and immutable map?

```
def - [A <: BothType] (o: A): ResourceHashMap = {
    o.forall {
        case (k, v) => this.contains(k) && this(k) >= v
    } match {
        case true => map {
            case (k, v) => k -> (v - o.getOrElse(k, 0))
        }
        case _ => null
    }
}
```

I know I can use `Map` trait, but it has not foreall and getOrElse method

Comment: Keep in mind that it's very rarely useful to define a type parameter that will be used once with a subtyping constraint on it as you did. `def -(o: BothType): ResourceHashMap` will behave equivalently in most cases. Style-wise, I'd also avoid pattern matching on a `Boolean` or returning a `null`, if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you call `BothType` is actually a `scala.collection.Map`. Try importing it and using then.

Comment: Map has not forall and getOrElse method

Comment: @Pooya according to the 2.10 [Scala API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Map), scala.collection.Map has both `forall` and `getOrElse` defined

Comment: @DavidKaczynski It was a mistake due to older version of Scala